# How do "certificates" hold "keys"?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure

I am new to the realm of security and keep hearing about "*certificates*" containing "*keys*". But no one has been able to actually explain to me what is actually meant by this.

I *assume* that the cryptographic *key* is really just a numeric/alpha-numeric identifier that can be represented in plaintext. Yes?

Furthermore, I *assume* that a *certificate* is nothing more than a plaintext file literally containing 1+ of these keys. Yes?

If my assumptions are correct, can someone just please confirm them (I think that would be enormously helpful for future newcomers who are *really* trying to understand the fundamentals)? And if my assumptions are incorrect or mislead, can someone please correct them for me?

Answer (score 2):

Yes they can be represented in plain text. both your assumptions can be true.

Most certificates usually follow the [x509 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) based on [RFC5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280)

A x509 Certificate can be represented in a [PEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-enhanced_Electronic_Mail) format - which is plaintext. It can include an entire certificate chain including public key, private key, and root certificates.

there are also [other formats](https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file) that exist like [PKCS12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12) which may require a password as they can hold the private key.

If you are a newcomer, then the [Link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work) suggested by @BadSkillz is the best place to start.